# Is there any performance cost to always use this pointer in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

Is there any performance cost to dereference `this->` pointer
or is it okay to use.

For example:-

```
Vertex::Vertex(int data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->visited = false;
}
```

Comment: performance cost as compared to what?

Comment: just a matter of style (unless you use dependent name whereas `this->` or qualified name is required, but independent of performance anyway).

Comment: Without using `this->` in the example code assignment `data = data;` will be noop.

Comment: performance cost compared to not using this pointer and using other coding styles like m_variable

Comment: `visited = false;` and `this->visited = false;` mean exactly the same thing, and there is no good reason for a compiler to generate different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `this->` pointer for dereferencing as shown is *optional*, and has absolutely no impact on the meaning or the code generated.

There are people who think it's better readable, and people who think it's not, but that's the only difference.

As others recommended, either way, chose a different name for the parameter than the member's name. The compiler will know what you mean, but humans will stumble over the identical names.

Answer (score 6):

There is almost certainly no performance cost, unless you have a particularly bad compiler (or interpreter). The C++ standard does not explicitly say there *mustn't* be a performance cost, but then again it also refrains from stating the obvious to compiler writers.

`this->data` &c. are merely syntactic sugar for the member variable of the current object: writing `data = data;` in the constructor body is essentially a no-op. Better still, write

```
Vertex::Vertex(int data) : data(data), visited(false)
{
}
```

where here the compiler is able to disambiguate the variables comprising `data(data)`.

Comment: I think it would be better to suggest to avoid name collisions by using prefixes for class member .

Comment: @VTT: That's what I do, but it's by no means a universally accepted style. The Java guys seem to have explicitly moved towards it.

Comment: Well, using prefixes is definitely a better alternative to playing "spot the missing this->" game.

Comment: @VTT: I quite agree! It also means I can identify member variables in environments (such as vi) that don't have syntax highlighting.

Comment: ...if your method requires you to scroll down till you dont see the parameter list then maybe the method is just too big ;)